# How to make php echo a sub section of an array

Tags: php

index.php

```
<?php
$filename = "101.txt";

$file = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

print_r($file);
echo "</br>".$file[1];
?>
```

101.txt

```
1, 100, 001.txt
101, 200, 002.txt
201, 300, 003.txt
301, 400, 004.txt
```

Results of index.php

```
Array ( [0] => 1, 100, 001.txt [1] => 101, 200, 002.txt [2] => 201, 300, 003.txt [3] => 301, 400, 004.txt )
101, 200, 002.txt
```

What I want is something like

```
$file[1][1];
```

Which would export "200" instead of the full string.
Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: just use a simple foreach and explode every string element

Comment: @Ghost, that is essentially what my answer is doing, just more elegantly.

Comment: @ilovepoker still alive ?? Let us know if you got it working.

Comment: @PedroLobito's answer worked for me, thanks, although this is still a work in progress if I have any problems with this section i'll ask.

Comment: Ouch, no love for my answer.  I thought it was pretty awesome.

Comment: @ilovepoker ok, fair enough.

Comment: @Devon I'll +1 your answer for your effort ;)

Comment: @Devon srry I would +1 your answer if I could but I dont have the rep to

Comment: @ilovepoker, didn't realize you needed rep to up vote.  Been a long time for me I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$filename = "101.txt";
$file = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$value = explode(', ', $file[1]); //explode the 2nd array
echo $value[1]; //echo the 2nd value of 2nd array
//200
```

---

References:

http://php.net/explode

Answer (score 1):

**[array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)** can walk through the array and run a callback.  For instance, a function that explodes the value by commas.  Below is an example of an anonymous function with array_walk.

```
array_walk($file, function(&$value, $key) {
   $value = explode(', ', $value);
});
```

converts `$file`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1, 100, 001.txt
    [1] => 101, 200, 002.txt
    [2] => 201, 300, 003.txt
    [3] => 301, 400, 004.txt
)
```

to multi-dimensional `$file`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 001.txt
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 101
            [1] => 200
            [2] => 002.txt
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 201
            [1] => 300
            [2] => 003.txt
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 301
            [1] => 400
            [2] => 004.txt
        )

)
```

in which you can access '200' at `$file[1][1]`.

This works because *$value*, the value of each array element, is a reference (note `&$value`).  So you can modify it and it will update the original array.